# How to horizontally align these checkboxes?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to horizontal and vertical align these radios/checkboxes also I want the text to be in the left side of them. I tried some things like inline and block but I am fairly beginner and trying to learn.

Here is the HTML and CSS code for my small project:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 3.125rem auto 0 auto;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #1b1b32;
  color: white;
  font-family: Consolas, serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  background-blend-mode: color;
}

fieldset {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-color: #6b6b8d;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

input,
textarea,
select {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #0a0a23;
  background-color: #0a0a23;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-indent: 5px;
}

.input-radio,
.input-checkbox {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 1.25rem;
  min-width: 1.25rem;
}

.inline-field {
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* I added this after I posted my reply */
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* Fixes any weird issues in Firefox and IE */
}

.input-textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 120px;
  text-indent: 5px;
}

.submit-button {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  background-color: #3b3b4f;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-color: #6b6b8d;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Survey Registration Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="survey.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 id="title">Pepe's Survey Form</h1>
    <p id="description">Thank you for taking time to help us improve the platform</p>
    <form method="post" action="https://register-demo.freecodecamp.org" id="survey-form">
      <fieldset>
        <label id="name-label">Enter your first name:<input class="form-control" id="name" type="text"
                                                                        placeholder="Enter your name" required></label>
        <label id="email-label">Email:<input class="form-control" id="email" type="email"
                                                         placeholder="Enter your email" required></label>
        <label id="number-label">Age(optional)<input class="form-control" id="number" type="number"
                                                                 placeholder="Enter your age" required min="18"
                                                                 max="100"></label>
        <label for="referrer">How did you hear about us?
                        <select class="dropdown" id="referrer" name="referrer">
                            <option disabled selected value>Select current trading style</option>
                            <option value="1">Intraday Trader</option>
                            <option value="2">Swing Trader</option>
                            <option value="3">Investor</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
        <div class="inline-field">
          <label class="input-radio"><input class="input-radio" id="Yes" name="Yes-No" checked
                                                          type="radio" value="Yes">Yes</label>
          <label class="input-radio"><input class="input-radio" id="No" name="Yes-No" type="radio"
                                                          value="No">No</label>
        </div>


        <label class="input-checkbox">What would you like to see improved?
                        <small>(Check all that apply)</small>
                        <input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="more-charts">More Charts
                        <input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="new-screener">New Screener
                        <input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="better-execution">Better execution speed
                        <input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="blog-page">Blog Page
                    </label>
        <label>Any comments or suggestions?
                        <textarea class="input-textarea" id="Textarea" rows="3" cols="30"
                                  placeholder="I want this feature.."></textarea>
                    </label>
        <label>
                        <input class="submit-button" id="submit" type="submit">
                    </label>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You want to align them vertically and horizontally? So stack them in the Z axis? Or do you actually want to align them on the left, one after the other vertically? Please [edit] your question to be clear about the intent.

Comment: I want to align them on the left. one after the other vertically

Answer (score 0):

You can create rows using flexbox. Below is an example:

HTML:

```
<div class="input flex row">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label>Label</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}

.flex.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Click below for more information on how to use flexbox:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: fun fact that we both proposed the same flexbox link :D definitly the best page on the whole internet to understand flexbox :D

Answer (score 0):

Small improvement proposal to your inital code.

I would advise you to go through the 'flex' layout concept (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to handle your placement more easily :)

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #1b1b32;
  color: white;
  font-family: Consolas, serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 3.125rem auto 0 auto;
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  background-blend-mode: color;
  
}

fieldset {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-color: #6b6b8d;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input,
textarea,
select {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #0a0a23;
  background-color: #0a0a23;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-indent: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

.input-group + .input-group {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.input-group-v label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input-group-v input,
.input-group-v textarea,
.input-group-v select {
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group-h {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

.input-group-h label {
  width: 200px;
}
.input-group-h label.small {
  width: 50px;
}
.input-group-h .input-checkbox + label {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.input-radio,
.input-checkbox {
  display: block;
  min-height: 1.25rem;
  min-width: 1.25rem;
}

.input-textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 120px;
  text-indent: 5px;
}

.submit-button {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  background-color: #3b3b4f;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-color: #6b6b8d;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <h1 id="title">Pepe's Survey Form</h1>
  
  <p id="description">Thank you for taking time to help us improve the platform</p>
  
  <form method="post" action="https://register-demo.freecodecamp.org" id="survey-form">
    
    <fieldset>

      <div class='input-group input-group-v'>
        <label id="name-label">Enter your first name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required />
      </div>

      <div class='input-group input-group-v'>
        <label id="email-label">Email:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required />
      </div>

      <div class='input-group input-group-v'>
        <label id="number-label">Age(optional)</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="number" type="number" placeholder="Enter your age" required min="18" max="100" />
      </div>

      <div class='input-group input-group-v'>
        <label for="referrer">How did you hear about us?</label>
        <select class="dropdown" id="referrer" name="referrer">
          <option disabled selected value>Select current trading style</option>
          <option value="1">Intraday Trader</option>
          <option value="2">Swing Trader</option>
          <option value="3">Investor</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class='input-group input-group-h'>
        <label class="small">Yes</label>
        <input class="input-radio" id="Yes" name="Yes-No" checked type="radio" value="Yes" />
      </div>

      <div class='input-group input-group-h'>
        <label class="small">No</label>
        <input class="input-radio" id="No" name="Yes-No" type="radio" value="No" />
      </div>

      <h5>
        What would you like to see improved?<small>(Check all that apply)</small>
      </h5>

      <div class='input-group input-group-h'>
        <input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="more-charts" />
        <label>More Charts</label>
      </div>

      <div class='input-group input-group-h'>
        <input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="new-screener" />
        <label>New Screener</label>
      </div>

      <div class='input-group input-group-h'>
        <input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="better-execution" />
        <label>Better execution speed</label>
      </div>

      <div class='input-group input-group-h'>
        <input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="blog-page" />
        <label>Blog Page</label>
      </div>

      <div class='input-group input-group-v'>
        <label>Any comments or suggestions?</label>
        <textarea 
          class="input-textarea" 
          id="Textarea" 
          rows="3" 
          cols="30"
          placeholder="I want this feature.."
        ></textarea>
      </div>

      <input class="submit-button" id="submit" type="submit">
    </fieldset>            
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much. I see you added lots and lots of div classes may I ask why? isnt it complicate stuff?

 
can we not make this 1 big div for example?

Comment: well this is kind of usual to group the label and input together inside a div, specially when you want to apply a specific layout. Note that there are no 'perfect answer' and it's all about your personnal preference in the end :D

Comment: thank you very much. One last thing to ask. How can I put my text left side of the radio buttons and close to them ( almost stick to the text ) ?

Comment: they are not close to each other because you put a 'margin: auto' which tries to fill the empty space. Beware that when text is left the length of the text on each row can become a problem when trying to align (there is no way to know which text is the longest in css, so either switch to a 'grid' layout as suggested in another answer or make an asumption on the max length of the text) - I will update the sample to have the radio & check box closer.

Comment: I understand. Then it would be wiser to put radio buttons on the left side and text on closer to them on right ? So that text length wont be a problem

Comment: either put them on the left side or push them to the right side totally. you can get inspiration from big compagnies designs like for instance google materials > https://m2.material.io/components/radio-buttons#usage

Comment: thank you very much. Is it easy to put the buttons on the left side. I am fairly new couldn't understand the margin stuff. I am trying to customize margin-left:0 so that it will be on the left but..

Also why did you but input-group-v on my html while you are not using it at all on CSS

Comment: if you want the input to be on the left side, put them before the labels (in your initial code the input were inside the labels which I consider tedious :D)

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.. thank you very much but still the checkboxes are on the middleish. I cant seem to put them attached on the left side.

Comment: updated sample with box to the left :p

Answer (score 0):

To ensure alignment in both the horizontal and vertical axes, use a [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) to lay out your checkboxes.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 3.125rem auto 0 auto;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #1b1b32;
  color: white;
  font-family: Consolas, serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  background-blend-mode: color;
}

fieldset {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-color: #6b6b8d;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

input,
textarea,
select {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #0a0a23;
  background-color: #0a0a23;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-indent: 5px;
}

.input-radio,
.input-checkbox {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 1.25rem;
  min-width: 1.25rem;
}

.inline-field {
  display: inline;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* I added this after I posted my reply */
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* Fixes any weird issues in Firefox and IE */
}

.input-textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 120px;
  text-indent: 5px;
}

.submit-button {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  background-color: #3b3b4f;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-color: #6b6b8d;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.d1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content auto;
  gap: 0 1em;
  margin: 10px 0 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 id="title">Pepe's Survey Form</h1>
  <p id="description">Thank you for taking time to help us improve the platform</p>
  <form method="post" action="https://register-demo.freecodecamp.org" id="survey-form">
    <fieldset>
      <label id="name-label">Enter your first name:<input class="form-control" id="name" type="text"
                                                                      placeholder="Enter your name" required></label>
      <label id="email-label">Email:<input class="form-control" id="email" type="email"
                                                       placeholder="Enter your email" required></label>
      <label id="number-label">Age(optional)<input class="form-control" id="number" type="number"
                                                               placeholder="Enter your age" required min="18"
                                                               max="100"></label>
      <label for="referrer">How did you hear about us?
                      <select class="dropdown" id="referrer" name="referrer">
                          <option disabled selected value>Select current trading style</option>
                          <option value="1">Intraday Trader</option>
                          <option value="2">Swing Trader</option>
                          <option value="3">Investor</option>
                      </select>
                  </label>


      <label class="input-checkbox">What would you like to see improved?
        <small>(Check all that apply)</small>
        <div class="d1">
          More Charts <input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="more-charts">
          New Screener <input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="new-screener">
          Better execution speed <input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="better-execution">
          Blog Page <input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="blog-page">
        </div>
      </label>
      <label>Any comments or suggestions?
        <textarea class="input-textarea" id="Textarea" rows="3" cols="30"
                  placeholder="I want this feature.."></textarea>
      </label>
      <label>
        <input class="submit-button" id="submit" type="submit">
      </label>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much. may I ask why did radio buttons disappear in this example?

Comment: They didn't seem to belong to anything, so I just removed them.

Answer (score 0):

Does this fit your vision?

If not, what could I improve?

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #1b1b32;
  color: white;
  font-family: Consolas, serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 3.125rem auto 0 auto;
}

h1,
p {
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-width: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  background-blend-mode: color;
  
}

fieldset {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-color: #6b6b8d;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input,
textarea,
select {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #0a0a23;
  background-color: #0a0a23;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-indent: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

.input-group + .input-group {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.input-group-v label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.input-group-v input,
.input-group-v textarea,
.input-group-v select {
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group-h {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
}

.input-group-h label {
  width: 200px;
}
.input-group-h label.small {
  width: 50px;
}
.input-group-h .input-checkbox + label {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.input-radio,
.input-checkbox {
  display: block;
  min-height: 1.25rem;
  min-width: 1.25rem;
  display:inline-flex;
}

.input-textarea {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 120px;
  text-indent: 5px;
}

.submit-button {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  background-color: #3b3b4f;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-color: #6b6b8d;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.checkbox-container{
display:inline-flex;

}

.group-g{
margin-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <h1 id="title">Pepe's Survey Form</h1>
  
  <p id="description">Thank you for taking time to help us improve the platform</p>
  
  <form method="post" action="https://register-demo.freecodecamp.org" id="survey-form">
    
    <fieldset>

      <div class='input-group input-group-v'>
        <label id="name-label">Enter your first name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required />
      </div>

      <div class='input-group input-group-v'>
        <label id="email-label">Email:</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required />
      </div>

      <div class='input-group input-group-v'>
        <label id="number-label">Age(optional)</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="number" type="number" placeholder="Enter your age" required min="18" max="100" />
      </div>

      <div class='input-group input-group-v'>
        <label for="referrer">How did you hear about us?</label>
        <select class="dropdown" id="referrer" name="referrer">
          <option disabled selected value>Select current trading style</option>
          <option value="1">Intraday Trader</option>
          <option value="2">Swing Trader</option>
          <option value="3">Investor</option>
        </select>
      </div>
     
      <div class='input-group input-group-h'>
        <label class="small">Yes</label>
        <input class="input-radio" id="Yes" name="Yes-No" checked type="radio" value="Yes" />
      </div>

      <div class='input-group input-group-h'>
        <label class="small">No</label>
        <input class="input-radio" id="No" name="Yes-No" type="radio" value="No" />
      </div>
      

      <h5>
        What would you like to see improved?<small>(Check all that apply)</small>
      </h5>
      <div class="checkbox-container">
      <div class='input-group input-group-h'>
        <input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="more-charts" />
        <label>More Charts</label>
      </div>

      <div class='input-group input-group-h'>
        <input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="new-screener" />
        <label>New Screener</label>
      </div>

      <div class='input-group input-group-h group-g'>
        <input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="better-execution" />
        <label>Better execution speed</label>
      </div>
      <div class='input-group input-group-h'>
        <input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="blog-page" />
        <label>Blog Page</label>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class='input-group input-group-v'>
        <label>Any comments or suggestions?</label>
        <textarea 
          class="input-textarea" 
          id="Textarea" 
          rows="3" 
          cols="30"
          placeholder="I want this feature.."
        ></textarea>
      </div>

      <input class="submit-button" id="submit" type="submit">
    </fieldset>            
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much. I learned a lot. I manage to make it as I liked.